# Entity framework Models Access entity from another model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Model of `MyQueue` and `Service` I dunno how can I get the `ServiceLetter` on my `Services` model properly to render it on my view.

Here is my `MyQueue` Model.

```
public class MyQueue
{
    public int MyQueueId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string QueueNumber
    {
        get
        {


     return string.Format("{0}{1:000}", ServiceLetter ?? "?", MyQueueId);
        }
        set { }
    }

    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    public string ServiceLetter { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

here is my `Service` Model

```
public class Service
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    public string ServiceLetter { get; set; }
}
```

In my `dbo.MyQueues` my `ServiceLetter` data only shows number, I need it to become what ever letter I put on my `Service`

I want my `MyQueue` to be like this, ServiceLetter is Letter not Number,

**MyQueueId - Name - QueueNumber - ServiceId - ServiceLetter**

- 1 - JohnDoe - A001 - 1 - **A**
- 2 - DoeJogn - B002 - 2 - **B**
- 3 - JognDog - C002 - 3 - **C**

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you only look up the MyQueues data. You need to fetch the appropriate Service model.

When using Entityframework to interface with a database, you need to use the Include function. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Also take a look at join. The example on the bottom seems to explain things nicely https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ServiceId as Foreign Key in 'MyQueue'. And when you are accesing 'dbo.MyQueues', then please INCLUDE 'Service'

```
dbo.MyQueues.Include(q => q.Service);
```